# Remove Complete Li with Specific Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to remove a complete li with input only if you clicked on the [x] how i can do this ?

**UPDATE**
Here is a demo for my problem..
http://jsfiddle.net/vPU9z/3/

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should work out:

```
jQuery('li a').click(function(event){
    $(this).parent().remove();        
});
```

It selects all `a`s within an `li` and adds an eventlistener to them. In there we delete the parent of the `a`, which is the `li`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/vPU9z/

Comment: I suggest renaming the handler parameter to `event` as it could cause confusion, it's not an element. Just a good practice.

Comment: i have created a fiddle of my problem

Comment: @SaschaHeim Just run this snippet again for the newly inserted `a`-Tags

Comment: @SaschaHeim The one in my answer? This creates the needed Listener.

Comment: Have you seen my problem in my created fiddle in the first post ?

Answer (score -2):

Remove that jQuery rubbish, and just use this:

```
<li><a onClick="var t = this.parentNode; t.parentNode.removeChild(t);" href="javascript:void(null);">[x]</a> More stuff here</li>
```

Comment: Don't use the onClick, atleast put it inside a $(".class").click() type of thing so its modular.

Comment: Calling jQuery rubbish and using inline-JS :(

Comment: jQuery is rubbish, and if the inline JS works why not use it?

Comment: "why not use it"... separation of concerns? It's generally bad practice to use inline event handlers. I do agree that jQuery has its place, but DOM manipulation like this is very much in that place in my opinion.

Comment: @Kolink "why not use it" There are many things we can do in the world of programming. The fact that we can never justifies the act of doing so. Using the onclick may have its uses but I never would agree with loading multiple lines of js in an onclick attribute.

Comment: If you really want that code can be done in one command - I just split it up to lessen the number of `parentNode`'s in there.